# SUDO fixing problem

Tags: sudo

I am currently using ubuntu 18.04.I was trying to provide another user sudo permission.After editing visudo ,I can.t fix my sudo...

```
:~$ sudo
/etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 9
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 9
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
riyadh@riyadh-Inspiron-3593:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by creating a Ubuntu USB stick (like you would for installations). Boot from the USB and click "try Ubuntu without installing".

Once I was in the system I could mount my drive to /mnt, use `fdisk -l` to see the various drives and determine which is your drive. Then you can mount the drive

`mount /dev/(name of drive) /mnt`

Then, `cd /mnt/etc/` and open the file in your text editor of choice. I use vi so I would `vi sudoers`. Once you have edited the file then you can save it, power down the machine, remove the usb, and restart the machine to boot back into your Ubuntu installation.